# Как скопировать сразу три строчки в редакторе VI?

Tags: unix, администрирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в редакторе VI скопировать сразу три строчки текста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Встать на первой строке и нажать **3Y**. В результате три следующих строки будут скопированы. Или перейти в режим VISUAL, нажав v. Затем выделить, что требуется и нажать **y**

Comment: А если допустим, необходимо скопировать по середине текста, то принцип будет точно такой же? То есть копирование будет происходить от курсора?

Comment: Если по середине - это не в смысле по середине строки, то да. 3Y будет копировать именно строки, нгачиная от строки в которой находится курсор.

Comment: Да именно строки, понял, спасибо большое.

Comment: Дополню: перейти в режим VISUAL можно в построчном (а не посимвольном, по-умолчанию) режиме с помощью shift+v.

Comment: Так же дополню, вставить строки можно кнопкой p или P (перед или после курсора).